I can't get ufw to use nftables in the background for sshguard
I've been struggling with adding another layer of security for my ssh. The thing is when I try to use sshguard with sshg-fw-nft-sets value, iptables gives me error. I can't restart ufw without an iptables error. It's either chain sshguard missing or directory not found when I add the chain manually.
# Create a chain for SSHGuard
-A ufw-before-input -j SSHGUARD
-A ufw-before-output -j SSHGUARD
-A ufw-before-forward -j SSHGUARD

If I go with iptables installation, it works okay but I can't use ufw then because I need to run:
sudo apt install iptables-persistent

which uninstalls ufw.
What am I doing wrong?
The guide link
